# FirebaseApp.configuration() unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I'm creating a social app (out of personal interest) using Xcode on my macOS Catalina 10.15.6 and facing tons of config issues before really doing something.

I'm stuck in this swift compiler error for 2 days already: **Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'**

I've updated Ruby successfully.

I followed the instructions on the firebase official website

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

I've met bumps all along after executing "pod init" in Terminal. This was solved after I updated Ruby. I've got some help from Stack Overflow posts but couldn't find the one that solve my problem.

Comment: Which Xcode version you have?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the official documentation regarding the setup misleading. Therefore I use `import FirebaseCore` when implementing `FirebaseApp.configure()` and not as suggested `import Firebase`.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: How exactly did you structure your Podfile?

I have also been following the standard Firebase setup docs for iOS (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup), but have been unable to directly import FirebaseCore as suggested.

Comment: Hi @StevenD. I'm not using Pods to integrate Firebase. We have a shell script which downloads and extracts the frameworks from here (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases/download/CocoaPods-6.30.0/Firebase.zip). Than we link the frameworks (especially FirebaseCore.xcframework) with the project through a dedicated build phase. Remember to add the location of the extracted Firebase framework to your targets search paths in its settings. Thats it.